# Jboss drools 5.4.0.Final with JDK 7

Tags: java, drools

Trying to write a consequence of a rule which uses diamond operator. Getting the following error message. java.version system property is set to 1.7 and JavaDialectConfiguration class gets the language level as 1.7, still why drools is not able to compile diamond operator?

```
Incorrect number of arguments for type HashMap<K,V>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <?>
```

Sample Rule :

```
package rule.test;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

dialect "java"

rule "Test jdk 7"
when
then
Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<>();
end
```

Comment: Bad luck! Yesterday I uninstall the eclipse plugin for Drools!

Comment: Can you include the rule declaration that is causing the error?

Comment: provided the sample rule

Comment: Have you tried with `5.5.0.Final` or `6.0.0.CR1`?

Answer (score 0):

drools compiler maven artifact of 5.4.0.Final or 5.5.0.Final are pulling 3.5.1 version of eclipse core compiler.

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
<artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
<version>3.5.1</version>
```

When I put latest version of JDT compiler into my pom, the issue gets resolved.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
<artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
<version>4.2.2</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If this solves the problem, I think that you can accept the answer.